# Simulate a queue using Lindley's equation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, queue

I have to simulate a simple queue in Matlab using Lindley's equation:

```
W_{n+1}^Q = max(0, W_n^Q + S_n - X_{n+1}
```

I think I have done so, with the following code, but I am trying to run it several times and cannot save the information correct.  The variables I want to save at the end of running the simulation are only saving the information from the last attempt (here for m=3).. while I clearly would like to see this for all runs (m=1,2,3).

```
for m=1:3
l = 1.1; % try this value for lambda
N = 10000; % let 1000 people arrive

X = exprnd(l,[1,N]); % make 1000 exponential interarrivals
S = 2*rand(1,N); % uniform on [0,2]
w = zeros(1,N);

sum1 = zeros(1,m);
avg1 = zeros(1,m);
max1 = zeros(1,m);

for i=1:N
    if i==1 % first customer doesn't have to wait
        w(i) = 0;
    else % following customers follow lindley's equation
        w(i) = max(w(i-1) + S(i-1) - X(i), 0); % n-th customer's waiting time
        count(i) = w(i) > 15; % count number of times greater than 15
    end

end
        max1(m) = max(w);
        sum1(m) = sum(count); % sum number of times greater than 15
        avg1(m) = sum1(m)/N; % divide by 1000 to get probability delay is greater than 15
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing **sum1**, **avg1** and **max1** inside the *for* loop so in every iteration, these variables are set to zero (i.e. by initialization). This is the reason you loose your previous iteration value. To avoid this, initialize **sum1**, **avg1** and **max1** before you *for* loop. Refer below code for reference. HTH

```
sum1 = zeros(1,m);
avg1 = zeros(1,m);
max1 = zeros(1,m);

for m=1:3
l = 1.1; % try this value for lambda
N = 10000; % let 1000 people arrive

X = exprnd(l,[1,N]); % make 1000 exponential interarrivals
S = 2*rand(1,N); % uniform on [0,2]
w = zeros(1,N);


for i=1:N
    if i==1 % first customer doesn't have to wait
        w(i) = 0;
    else % following customers follow lindley's equation
        w(i) = max(w(i-1) + S(i-1) - X(i), 0); % n-th customer's waiting time
        count(i) = w(i) > 15; % count number of times greater than 15
    end

end
        max1(m) = max(w);
        sum1(m) = sum(count); % sum number of times greater than 15
        avg1(m) = sum1(m)/N; % divide by 1000 to get probability delay is greater than 15
end
```

Comment: Okay great, it first said undefined variable m, but then changing to zeros(1,3) it worked, thanks!